# How to specify xampp mysql port number during bitnami wordpress installation?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, xampp, bitnami

I have installed xampp and I changed the mysql port number from 3306 to 3307 ( as 3306 is blocked for other application). Both apache and mysql are running when I press start. **By the way, I am using Windows**

When I try to install bitnami wordpress module, the installer is not able to find mysql as the installer is looking for it on port number 3306 instead of 3307. I have checked the bitrock_installer.log and found out that it is indeed looking for mysql on port numner 3306.

```
Log started 05/01/2017 at 14:36:22 Preferred installation mode : qt Trying to init installer in mode qt Mode qt successfully initialized Tried to find file "properties.ini" inside non-existent directory "C:\Bitnami" Executing C:/xampp\mysql\bin/mysql.exe -u root -P3306
-hlocalhost -e "show databases;" Script exit code: 1

Script output:  

Script stderr:  ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Error running C:/xampp\mysql\bin/mysql.exe -u root -P3306 -hlocalhost
-e "show databases;": ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

**Is there a way to specify the mysql port number during bitnami wordpress installation, so that it looks for mysql on port number 3307 instead of 3306 ?** Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

During the WordPress installation process, you should select the directory where your XAMPP is installed. If you select a directory that contains a XAMPP installed using non-default ports (for example Apache [81,444] and MySQL [3307]), WordPress installation will use the same ports that are defined in the configuration files inside the XAMPP directory.

[image: selectFolder]

Comment: I selected the directory (i.e. c:\xampp) where XAMPP is installed but still no luck. The log error remained the same. Wordpress installation is still looking at port 3306 for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

As of Jul'17 there is no way to specify MySql port number. Following is the response I got from Bitnami Developer:

> I am afraid that we do not support a different port by default. My
>   advice would be to restart mysql in port 3306, perform the
>   installation and then switch it back to your custom port. Note that
>   you will also need to change the wp-config.php file so it uses the
>   proper database port. Would that work for you?

You can check the thread here: https://community.bitnami.com/t/xampp-bitnami-wordpress-module-custom-mysql-port/50538

Comment: Thanks Vivek Athalye